# How to use dictionary look up on websites that prevent it?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, dictionary

Typically, I triple-tap to search up a word or bring up an apple dictionary. Some websites, however, prevent this. Is there anyway I can override this? I am using Chrome. An example website would be membean.com during a vocab training session.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I've added an answer based on what I *think* you're asking, but if I've misunderstood it, can you please clarify what it is you're saying that some websites actually prevent? Perhaps provide an example of a site. Also, please confirm what browser you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you should be able to use the context menu to select the Look Up option.

More specifically:

1. In your browser double-click on a word to select it
2. Then right-click (or use ctrl+click) to bring up the context menu (e.g. if you double-click on the word `house` to select it and then right-click on it, you'll see a context menu such as:

[image]

3. From this menu you can select the top Look Up option and then you'll get the dictionary definition.

Comment: Some websites which disallow triple tap, might also *ban* double tap.. Ofc, no-one can make the universal answer, but if OP gives a sample website, we can try workarounds..